# Provisioning Profiles, certificates and such

Tags: objective-c, ios, code-signing, provisioning, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to understand the whole provisioning-proccess, but I just don't get it..

I have tried to read up, but it's too weird and difficult for me to understand, especially when English is neither my primary or secondary language..

I have been developing for a while, and I remember stressing alot when setting up my iphone for development the first time. When I go into `Settings->General` on my phone I have 17 profiles, but at least I got it working in the end.

Now, I'm porting my app to iPad, and I'm trying to add my iPad to the table.
This is what I did:
I went to developer.apple.com, added my udid in devices, I then went to `provisioning` on the same webpage, and saw three profiles, one uneditable(controlled by xcode), one connected to my app's AppID, and one connected to myself as an AppID.

I added my new iPad-device to all three of them to be sure, and downloaded them again.
I dragged the .mobileprovisions to iTunes and to Xcode, and I went into organizer and clicked `Refresh` to update them. I clicked `Use for development` on my iPad, and it says it contains those profiles. They're also in `Settings->General` on my iPad.

In my XCode project, I go under `Targets->Build Settings->Code Signing`, and set one of my new profiles to `Debug`, and one of the other to `Any iOS Sdk` inside it. I've tried multiple combinations. I also went to `Project->Build Settings->Code Signing` and did the same thing.

When I run my app on my device, it pops up two of the same error message saying `A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.`

When I now connect my iPhone, which has been working perfectly fine all along, the exact same thing happens. Two of the same error message.

**The question:**

Which profiles goes where? What is the difference between the profile containing myself as an AppID and the one containing my actual app's ID as AppID? What is the difference between `Target->Build Settings` and `Project->Build Settings` when it comes to `Code Signing`?

Also, we spent a lot of time making push work, and out app is on AppStore rigth now, so I don't want to start deleting profiles and ID's, cause I think I read somewhere that that could make the notification stop working.

Oh, and I downloaded a new certificate as well at some point, containing the new profiles, and it ended up in keychain named  along with 1000 others..

Help :( ?

Sorry for long and extremely boring/noobish question.

Comment: "Sorry for long and extremely boring/noobish question." It's not a problem. We love answering questions! :). Anyway, I have to say for english not being your first or second language, you have very good english. It's beats many people who were born here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that after we had released our app to the AppStore, we forgot to put the "Edit Scheme->Run" back to Debug from Release. This had no effect on my iPhone because I have added it to the release-provisioning-test thing.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your code doesn't build because of a certificate issue - like you said at the end of your question - you "downloaded a new certificate at some point containing the profiles..." You need to understand that a certificate does not 'contain' profiles, but profiles are created and signed using a specific certificate. Check that you have the **private key** of this certificate - if the signing request was not issued by you, it will require someone else exporting this certificate for you from his own keychain. Keep in mind that downloading the certificate available in your developer account will not suffice.

As for everything else:

**Which profiles goes where?**
Make sure you're creating relevant profiles with correct bundle IDs for your apps. Distribution profiles should include AdHoc and AppStore profiles, while Development profiles are, well, for development :)

**What is the difference between the profile containing myself as an AppID and the one containing my actual app's ID as AppID?** 
Not sure what you mean here. Myself as an AppID? Each profile is linked to a specific App ID that has a bundle ID - it can be used to compile any app that has this bundle or any sub-domain of it in the info.plist of the project.

**What is the difference between Target->Build Settings and Project->Build Settings when it comes to Code Signing?**
You can think of your Project->Build Settings as the global settings and the Target->Build Settings as the target-specific settings. If XCode can't figure out which profile to use from the target settings, it will go and fetch it from the project settings.

Comment: But then I don't understand what I've done wrong..
I looked in my "Devices" list in the portal, and clicked "Details" next to my iPhone where it says "3(details), which contained three profiles. I went to provisioning, and added my new device to those three provisioning profiles, because my iPhone worked, so I figured I'd do the same to my iPad. Then I downloaded all three profiles, and the certificate, and now neither the iPhone or the iPad works..
What's the "real" way to add a device for development? Creating completely new profiles?

Comment: No, the way you added your device is fine. The problem is probably with the certificate. It's not enough to download it from the provisioning portal, just as I stated in the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Okay, but how do I connect them? I haven't deleted any certificates, I only downloaded one. So I should have the old one? Or did I overwrite something? I now have four keys named "<Key>".

Comment: Who issued the signing request for this certificate? If it were you, was it with the same identity? I would advise creating a new one but it would mean re-creating all your old profiles. Then again, it's much better doing something right once than tackling it over and over without understanding it.

Comment: I agree on your last statement, but wouldn't that mean our notification certificate also screws up? In that case I won't do it. But how can I find out which key is the right one? It was probably me "issuing the signing request", even though I have no idea what that means. In my keychain, I have loads of keys and sertificates, none of which tells what they're used for! When I downloaded the something.cer, and clicked on it, keychain opened and highlighted one of the one called "<Key>", which gives me nothing. I have no idea how to find the right one and what to do to it.

Comment: That may be a problem. There's no way I know of to map between the private key used for issuing a certificate signing request and the certificate. As to what you say about push services - I would consider including it in an update if it's already production but yes, it will screw up the existing push services.

Comment: I still don't understand anything about how certificates are connected with anything.. Is it only valid on one machine, one app, one project, and where are they connected? The certificate isn't mentioned once in xcode? I guess I'll have to try and read up on it again..

Comment: In this scenario, the certificate is in charge of identifying a specific developer. They are accessible via your keychain, which you already know about. The keychain also stores tons of other stuff (such as passwords you ask your browser to remember and such). A provisioning profile is linked to a certificate which identifies the developer. They can be shared between developers.

Comment: Hm, I created a new empty project in XCode, and I can run it on my iPad just fine.. Any idea where the problem could be then..?

Comment: and btw, I just noticed the error I get on my iPhone is not the same error as on the iPad. It says "Could not change executable permissions on the application."..

Comment: - as it turns out, my iPhone had an other version of the app, so I just had to delete the old app, and it worked fine.. But the iPad still doesn't work in this project, while it works in an empty one..

Comment: Aaand, I found out why. After releasing the app, we apparently forgot to set scheme back to debug from release. It worked on my iPhone because I have that profile there. I just added the iPad to the developer profiles.